# NSPredicate doesn't find the specified String

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, nspredicate

So I have set up a search in Core Data. It gets the text to search for from an text field and then tries to search for it using a predicate in a fetch request. Then the fetchedResultsController should insert it into the tableView.

```
private func search() {
        guard let searchPhrase = searchField.text else { return }

        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title contains[cd] %@", searchPhrase)

        do {
            try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
            var stuff = try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
            print(stuff)
            print("fetch Successful")
        } catch {
         fatalError("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

    }
```

The console output shows that stuff (the fetch result) is empty:

```
()
fetch Successful
```

I have 2 entities with the title "Harry Potter 1" and "Harry Potter 2".
I tested it with "Harry Potter on both and the console output is empty like above.

the variables are setup this way:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var searchField: UITextField!
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!
lazy var fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Book> = NSFetchRequest<Book>(entityName: "Book")
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Book> = {
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)]
    return NSFetchedResultsController<Book>(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
}()
```

managedObjectContext is being passed through by the presentingViewController.
So where is the problem?

Comment: what is `fetchRequest` and how is it related to `fetchedResultsController`, like you set the predicate on one thing then performFetch on a different thing

Comment: I wouldn't have a property for the fetch request, create it in the initialisation code for the fetch controller and if you need to update it later access the fetch controller property instead, fetchResultsController.fetchRequest

Comment: thx didn't knew that. Didn't solve the problem though :/

Comment: You need to debug. Only you know what is in your core data and what your actual predicate is. We can't do it from here. Basically you need to work from the known / working step by step to your use case. For example, fetch _all_ the data and see what you get. If it includes the Harry Potter managed objects, start trying different predicates that explicitly include "Harry Potter". And so on. If you get that to work, then you can concentrate on why it doesn't work with the text field. And finally, you can worry about the actual table view.

Comment: But to assure: title in the predicate is the attribute to look in. contains[cd] tells it that it should look if title contains the following. And searchPhrase is the string it should compare to the attribute. So the predicate looks for all entity instances where title contains Harry Potter in some form, right?

Comment: Since `performFetch` returns a boolean, what are you expecting to be printed here?

Comment: In Swift, `performFetch` returns nothing (aka `Void`), and that is what you see printed as `()`. – Perhaps you wanted to do  `var stuff = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects` ?  Or `var stuff  = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)` instead of using a fetched results controller?

Comment: Thx for helping. The real problem was that I forgot to set tableView.dataSource to self *facepalm*